# Using blank values in database?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

When a checkbox is left unchecked it will produce a blank value in the db field after submitting the form.

I can assign a value to empty checkboxes before submitting the form:

```
if (empty($checkbox1)){
 $checkbox1='none';
}
```

etc.

Is it better to have a bunch of empty fields in the db or a bunch of fields INSERTED with "none" ?
It seems to me "none" fields are redundant and would take up more space...

Comment: Don't worry about space.  The amount of space you're talking about is negligible.  It's premature optimization.

Comment: Ok so if checkbox1, checkbox3 are checked then those will be updated with the form values, and checkbox2, checkbox4, checkbox5 should be updated as "none" or left blank?

Comment: Make them blank, or better yet, make them NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should assign for that checkbox a db field that can assume two values: 0 and 1. One of them will be equal to "checked", the other one to "none"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following methods: enum, bit(1) or tinyint(1) because you are working with a boolean like variable.

If you are looking at performance the difference between enum and bit are not that bit: http://techhelplist.com/index.php/tech-tutorials/42-databases/65-mysql-performance-bit-vs-tinyint-vs-enum

But if you are looking at storage space used, enum and tinyint both use 8byte of storage compared to bit(1) that only uses 1bit. The datatype BOOLEAN in mysql is a synonym of tinyint(1), so watch out with using that type.

Thus, to conclude you can better use bit(1) to store the result of a checkbox compared to the earlier given enum solution.

For more reading on why not to use enum: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Answer (score 1):

The way i am doing this is to define the DB field as follows:

```
Type: Enum
Length/Values: 'yes', 'no'
Default as defined: no
```

With this approach you only need to do an update if a checkbox is checked (or changed state).

As mentioned by others space is negligible.